# Haarcascades in opencv

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-detection, face-recognition

I have seen multiple haarcascade xmls in opencv for face detection, eye detection , ear detection, Human body detection etc., But couldnt see proper documentation or explanation for these xmls.

For example in a application if I need to detect side faces which xml should I use and what are the parameters to be passed for `detectMultiScale`?

In some cases if I vary the parameters to `detectMultiScale` the false detections get reduced, but I did all the tests with trial and error method. I couldnt find any definite articles on explaining the use of each xml and parameters.

Can some one provide the documents on this if any, else some explanation on this would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has a built-in profile face classifier xml under **"..\data\haarcascades"**. If you want to create your own cascade classifier, you should follow [this procedure](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html). Here is [another link](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) regarding that.

To learn about the `detectMultiScale` method, check out the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale). To understand the how the classifier and its parameters work, check out the [viola-jones (2001) article](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf) or [its explanation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfdYYNamHZ8).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.139.4825) by Vadim Pisarevsky, one of the OpenCV developers, which may be helpful, in understanding some of the parameters.

On the other hand, if using OpenCV is not a hard requirement, please take a look at [vision.CascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetectorclass.html) in the Computer Vision System Toolbox for Matlab, which provides the same functionality. It also saves you the trouble of figuring out which xml file to use for profile faces.